# Spark-Scala Invalid dependency while loading class file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Type missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SQLImplicits.class'. Could not access type Encoder in package org.apache.spark.sql, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full rebuild may help if 'SQLImplicits.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.    SparkScala Unknown  Scala Problem.

---

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'. Could not access type Row in package org.apache.spark.sql, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.   SparkScala      Unknown Scala Problem

*I'm new to this world. Any help would be highly appreciated!!
I have installed both 2.11 versions of spark and scala.*

Answer (score 0):

This was caused due to d not matching the org.apache.spark.sql version with org.apache.spark core. make sure both have same version.

I hope this will solve the issue.